# Correct implementation of touched callback in Angular

Tags: angular

I was wondering what is a correct implementation of the touched callback in a custom control implementing NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR.

```
registerOnTouched(touched: () => {}) {
  this.touched = touched;
}
```

In particular I am wondering, whether clicking on a dropdown menu, but clicking outside and not selecting any value should call `this.touched()` or not. Is the touch callback to be taken to the letter or only reflect the control's value change?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * A control is marked `touched` once the user has triggered
  * a `blur` event on it.
  */
  get touched(): boolean { return this._touched; }
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L176)